# How can I access the Session Cookie in a Grails Service?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, grails, grails-2.0

I need to access the session cookie (JSESSIONID) from within a Grails Service. I know how to access it from a Servlet.

Edit: I use the Grails JAXRS plugin http://grails.org/plugin/jaxrs to access a Resource from a REST request.

**How can I access the Session Cookie JSESSIONID in a Grails Service?**

Comment: Is your service session scoped or a singleton?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I haven't choose a scope yet.

Comment: So singleton (the default). Just pass the session along from your controller. def someServiceMethod(session, arg1, arg2, ...)

Comment: @JoshuaMoore The service is not used in a controller it is used in a groovy class in /grails-app/resources/

Comment: Without a web request how do you expect to identify what session the request being processed is? You may want to post some code to get more help.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I use the Grails JAXRS plugin http://grails.org/plugin/jaxrs to access a Resource from a REST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have an access to the session in your Jersey REST Resource, you need to add a Request parameter to the Resource method, like:

```
@POST
public createData(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    def session = request.session
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you can use `SecurityRequestHolder.request.session` in services and src files (if you are using SpringSecurity). I'm not sure how well it works in a class. Honestly I would find another way.

I've learned that when I think I need to access the session anywhere else but from a controller I have an architectural problem. At that point I stop and rethink what I'm doing and why I'm doing it. Often Grails provides a better way to accomplish what I think I need to do with the session. As @JoshuaMoore has pointed out, the best approach to using sessions is to pass the session values to a class instance or service within a controller.

This may not be the answer you want, but in the long run debugging, testing, and maintenance will be be easier. You will be glad you redesigned it.